# Adding Firebase to custom framework in iOS does not work

Tags: ios, firebase, frameworks

Adding Firebase to custom framework in iOS does not work. When I import my framework to app it gives:

```
FirebaseManager.swift:11:8: No such module 'Firebase'
```

Is this something due to the way the lib is built for Firebase? 
Rest of the third-party cocopods work fine like alamofire.
In podspec I have:

```
    s.ios.dependency  'Firebase/Database'
    s.ios.dependency  'Firebase/Core'
```

podfile for framework looks like this:

```
target 'abcSDK' do



# Pods for abcSDK

target 'abcSDKUnitTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
    pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper', '~> 4.0'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
end


pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper', '~> 4.0'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Database' 
end
```

Comment: So did you find any solution for the same ?

Answer (score 3):

Firebase pods include static (instead of dynamic) libraries to enable supporting a minimum iOS version of 7.0. The downside of static libraries is that they don't work as custom framework dependencies.